# Elevate creditals with powershell via Local System Account

Tags: powershell, jenkins, start-process

I want to deploy code using powershell via Jenkins Job. This works fine in the powershell ise.

```
$username = "mydomain\builder"
$password = "notmypassword"
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))
$Arguments = "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Test.ps1 -NoNewWindow -WorkingDirectory C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 -NoLogo -NonInteractive"

Start-Process "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

But when I run it from Jenkins which use the local system I get the following error message.

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson5557889306949142167.ps1:7 char:1
+ Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credentials -ArgumentList $
```

If change I change the Jenkins service to another account it works. Why won't elevated permission work under the local system account?

note: the only code in test.ps1 is New-Item c:\scripts\new_file.txt

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a restriction on certain commands when a script is run under *LocalSystem*. This makes sense in terms of security, given that *LocalSystem*:

> has complete unrestricted access to local resources. This is also the disadvantage of LocalSystem because a LocalSystem service can do things that would bring down the entire system.

Reference: [MSDN, The LocalSystem Account](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There is a similar question at SuperUser: [Can not create process with elevated permissions from LocalSystem account](https://superuser.com/questions/682213/can-not-create-process-with-elevated-permissions-from-localsystem-account) with <s>no answer so far</s> a reference to this answer now.

There is a similar question at TechNet: [Runing PowerShell script with the permissions of the LocalSystem user](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/b93bb6c9-5682-4126-929b-8442f4af7598/runing-powershell-script-with-the-permissions-of-the-localsystem-user?forum=winserverpowershell) with answers suggesting to run the script via Task Scheduler.

I can think of using [`runas`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx) with `/savecred` and a `/user:...` with appropriate permissions whose password never expires. AFAIR you have to invoke `runas` with `/savecred` interactively once, enter the credentials and it will take the saved credentials from the next invocation onwards.

Comment: To save the credentials I opened a cmd prompt as local system like this
    `psexec -i -s cmd.exe`
you have to right click the psexec and tick run as administrator for this to work.
I then ran my powershell script for the first time. 

I was prompted for my password and then I got Acces Denied!!

In the end I've changed the jenkins account to use something else. However here's a solution that I didn't try

[link](http://www.brandonmartinez.com/2013/04/24/resolve-access-is-denied-using-psexec-with-a-local-admin-account)